# What is another way of outputting data from an array rather than var_dump or print_r?

Tags: php, debugging

I'm on a 3rd party software and when I output the data from the array using `var_dump()` or `print_r()`, it comes out messy.

Anyone know of a way to output the data in a hierarchical format or something more organized (or some script that does it for me)?

Thanks!

Comment: Just look at the source instead of the rendered HTML.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+inurl%3Asarmenhb&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq= sarmenhb has 69 profiles and counting

Answer (score 5):

If you mean messy, as in not formatted, you could use `<pre>` to get it to format it as it's printed.

Or write a function like so

```
function debug($debug) {

    if (is_array($debug)) {
         echo '<pre>' . print_r($debug, TRUE) . '</pre>';
    } else {

         echo $debug;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use print_a() from debuglib! http://phpdebuglib.de this is what you want :-)

You can throw in any array and it gets dispalyed in a nice table, also nested data.

You can put it inside the page or at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://kaloyan.info/krumo/

> Except the collapsible DHTML tree built around the structure of the dumped PHP variable, and the improved by the CSS looks, Krumo offers additional useful features.

...or install a "real" debugger like e.g. [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) combined with [netbeans with the php plugin](http://netbeans.org).